# soap set parameter java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, parameters, request

I am implementing a TV listing service and I have decided to use ROVI as my data provider.

They provide me with an API that allows me to exchange data between my application and their servers by means of SOAP requests.

Since I am programming in Java, I used wsimport to generate the classes that would enable me to interact with their server.

```
//Connection
service = new ListingsService();
port = service.getListingsServiceSoap();
```

I have come across a problem which Google doesn't seem to have the answer for.

According to their API, whenever I want to make a call to a SOAP service I have to add my API Key to the end of url.

The problem is, I don't know how to do that. Using the stubs generated by wsimport, I can create a request object as it should be; however the URL is not displayed as per their specification. The url I currently get is: http://api.rovicorp.com/v9/listingsservice.asmx and what is required is: http://api.rovicorp.com/v9/listingsservice.asmx?apikey=myAPIkey. I obtained that by printing the following code:

```
System.out.println(port.toString());
```

Trying to run the following code:

```
GetServicesRS servicesRS = port.getServices(getServicesRQ, auth)
```

Yields the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 403: Forbidden
```

What java method can I use to append this parameter into the SOAP request URL.

Thanks for your help.

Edit.

I am still struggling with this and haven't been lucky with responses, if anyone could point me in the direction of a framework or something that could facilitate this would be great!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to work around my problem using something called BindingProvider.

I added the following to my code:

```
//Connection
service = new ListingsService();
port = service.getListingsServiceSoap();
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
bindingProvider.getRequestContext()
.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
"http://api.rovicorp.com/v9/listingsservice.asmx?apikey=" + APIKey);
```

With the aforementioned code the call to the API is successful:

```
GetServicesRS servicesRS = port.getServices(getServicesRQ, auth)
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.